# Using Eclipse API tooling to enforce correct versions in Require-Bundle

Tags: eclipse, api, pde

Is it possible to make Eclipse API tooling to maintain versions MANIFEST.MF, so that when I use an API element which is annotated as (for example) `@since 1.1`, I get a warning of the corresponding `Require-Bundle` does not also specify a compatible version number?

I have a plugin `A`, which defines a class `X`. This class `X` was introduced in version 1.1:

```
/**
 * @since 1.1
 */
public class X {
}
```

I have another plugin `B`, which depends on A, version 1.0.0:

```
// MANIFEST.MF for plugin B
...
Require-Bundle: A;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

Note that the dependency on `A` specifies version 1.0.0, not version 1.1 which is necessary to be able to resolve the new class X.

I was under the impression that API tooling would warn about these kinds of things, but it doesn't seem to do that. (It does warn when introducing `X` that I need to bump the version of `A` to 1.1, so my API tooling setup seems at least to work that far.)

Is this outside of the scope of API tooling, or have I setup my API tooling incorrectly? (No API tooling warnings/errors are set to ignore.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to correlate @since with a version in Require-Bundle. But of course you can write down your own plugin ;-)